# When running Pulumi in powershell, it just opens a new file

Tags: powershell, pulumi

[image: Entering the command]

Whenever I try one of the options, it just creates a new blank file.
Doesn't matter what directory it's in, whether Pulumi is installed or not.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what output you get if you run `Get-Command Pulumi |Format-List`?

Comment: Yep I've added it above

Comment: Try invoking it like this: `& (Get-Command pulumi)`

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, just running `&  (Get-Command pulumi)` I get exactly the same problem as before
Did you mean `Get-Command Pulumi |Format-List & Get-Command Pulumi |Format-List` or `& (Get-Command Pulumi) |Format-List`
Either way they haven't worked

Answer (score 0):

You're running the command with a capital letter. It's just `pulumi` with a lower case `P`

Comment: Same happens with lower case